# Byte size and hashs?

Tags: encryption, hash, sha1

I was using a hash generator, and when you enter SHA1 into the lookup, it spits out 40 characters under SHA1.

So when I looked it up on the internet to see the byte size, it says 20 bytes, even though it's 40 characters?

I thought byte size was determined by characters? 1 character = one byte or am I wrong? Unless it's determined by bit size?

I looked it up to clarify if my assuming was correct on it being 40 bytes, but it's telling me it's 20 bytes, not 40.

Comment: Presumably you are looking at hexadecimal encoding. One byte is represented by two hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

Officially the outcome of the SHA-1 hash is 160 bits, and on modern computer those are represented by 20 bytes.

As the [FIPS 180-1 specification](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/FIPS/fipspub180-1.pdf) indicates:

> For a message of length < 2^64 bits, the SHA-1
> produces a 160-bit condensed representation of the message called a message digest.

The hexadecimals are just *a textual representation* of those 20 bytes. Those same bytes could also be e.g. base 64 encoded but `sha1sum` and other such utilities usually display (lowercase) hexadecimals, as the hash is limited in size by definition.

Note that SHA-1 is not considered secure anymore and the FIPS document is now withdrawn. Use SHA-2, SHA-3 or - in many cases - a good password hash such as Argon2 instead.